# Flutter Auth State not changing in Wrapper() when (user == null) => WelcomeScreen()

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, firebase-authentication

When I code if(user == null) => LoginScreen(), the screen will show me my login screen, which I need to press the login button so the screen will show me the main screen MainScreen(). Good news this works really well.

But I need the users to get to the welcome screen first (when user == null) so I changed the code at my Wrapper() from if(user==null){LoginScreen()} to if(user==null){WelcomePage()}. In the welcome screen, user will be navigated to the log in page (LoginScreen()) if they pressed login button, and so for register to the RegisterScreen().

This is the route that would be if (if(user == null)=> WelcomeScreen();):

`WelcomeSceen() => LoginScreen() => MainScreen()`

So the problem happened when the screen show me WelcomePage(), I pressed login button to be navigated to LoginScreen() then I pressed the login button (so I can be navigate to MainScreen()). The screen did not redirect me to the MainScreen(), but I have 'user is signed in' in my terminal(based on what I code at my wrapper). When I restart the app after that, the screen redirect me to the main screen.

Really need to know why this could be happened, and how to solve this so I can still show the users WelcomeScreen first.

Below is my code and the directories.

*main.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:uberclone/models/usermodel.dart';
import 'package:uberclone/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:uberclone/wrapper.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<UserModel?>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      initialData: null,
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*wrapper.dart* (**BEFORE CHANGE**)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:uberclone/models/usermodel.dart';
import 'package:uberclone/screens/authentication/loginscreen.dart';
import 'package:uberclone/screens/home/mainscreen.dart';

class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserModel?>(context);
    print(user);
    if (user == null) {
      return LoginScreen();
    } else {
      return MainScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

*wrapper.dart* (**AFTER CHANGE**)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:uberclone/models/usermodel.dart';
import 'package:uberclone/screens/authentication/welcomescreen.dart';
import 'package:uberclone/screens/home/mainscreen.dart';

class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserModel?>(context);
    print(user);
    if (user == null) {
      return WelcomeScreen();
    } else {
      return MainScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

*auth.dart*

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:uberclone/models/usermodel.dart';

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  UserModel? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
    return user != null ? UserModel(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  Stream<UserModel?> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      User? user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

*loginscreen.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uberclone/screens/authentication/registerscreen.dart';
import 'package:uberclone/screens/authentication/welcomescreen.dart';
import 'package:uberclone/services/auth.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String idScreen = 'loginscreen';
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WelcomeScreen()),
            );
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_rounded),
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Please sign in',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 3),
                      child: TextField(
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: 'Email Address',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 15),
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 3),
                      child: TextField(
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        obscureText: true,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: 'Password',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 2),
                    TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => RegisterScreen()),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'Dont have any Veko Driver account? Register here',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Color(0xff0466c8), fontSize: 15),
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 320),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    MaterialButton(
                      height: 55,
                      onPressed: () async {
                        dynamic result = await _auth.signInAnon();
                        if (result == null) {
                          print('user has not signed in');
                        } else {
                          print('user has signed in');
                          print(result.uid);
                        }
                      },
                      elevation: 0,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      child: Text(
                        'Log in',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*welcomescreen.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uberclone/screens/authentication/loginscreen.dart';
import 'package:uberclone/screens/authentication/registerscreen.dart';
import 'package:uberclone/screens/authentication/safetyscreen.dart';

class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String idScreen = 'welcomescreen';
  @override
  _WelcomeScreenState createState() => _WelcomeScreenState();
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/veko-rider-coverpage7.jpg')),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 15, bottom: 5),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      'Welcome to the Veko',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      'Driver app',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 15),
                  Container(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        MaterialButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => LoginScreen()),
                            );
                          },
                          elevation: 0,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          height: 40,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 40, vertical: 10),
                            child: Text(
                              'Sign in',
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                        MaterialButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => RegisterScreen()),
                            );
                          },
                          elevation: 0,
                          color: Colors.grey[200],
                          height: 40,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 38, vertical: 10),
                            child: Text(
                              'Register',
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Divider(
              color: Colors.grey[400],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  MaterialButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3, vertical: 5),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                            context, SafetyScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_rounded)),
                  SizedBox(width: 8),
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: Text(
                          'or Ride with Veko',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There is **way** too much code here for anyone to efficiently help. Please take the time to reproduce the problem in isolation. Following the guidance in [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) drastically increases the chances that someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Hope so you solved your issue till now,
I'm a newbie to flutter & I was going through the same problem actually and didn't find a proper solution...And this thread seems to be a dead-end. So I want to leave this answer for the others although you asked this 9 months ago.

The problem is that you have already navigated to another page in the widget tree.

For example initially your widget tree (navigation stack) when the user is going to login is like:

**WelcomeScreen() => LoginScreen()**

When the user enters his credentials and presses login, the change indeed, does happen and the widget tree looks like the following:

**MainScreen() => LoginScreen()**

To simplify things...the change did take place but you were already standing on the Login screen (i.e. The LoginScreen was on the top of the navigation stack and the change of Main Screen occurred one place back in the navigation stack).

For it's solution, (in my case at-least since I wanted animation too) I used an animated switcher between WelcomeScreen and LoginScreen (So in theory my navigation stack will always contain 1 page).

Another solution(lousy but ok) is that you can use Wrapper for the LoginScreen and MainScreen instead for the WelcomeScreen and MainScreen so it always the top page that gets replaced... but the problem with this solution is that everytime you will hot reload the WelcomeScreen for sure will be displayed till you navigate to the LoginScreen (this is where decision will take place and you will be shown appropriate screen).